# Oracle SP Fails when called from Apex form due to date format

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table where I am inserting and updating data using a Procedure based on the input parameters. The procedure is called from Oracle APEX form.
The Procedure works fine in Oracle. But when I call it from Apex form, I get the Procedure fail error. On analysis, I found that this is because of the date format mismatch in the value passed from Apex form and in Oracle.

```
Date format in APEX FORM-->16-AUG-2017
```

`Date format in ORACLE DB-->2017-08-17`

Do I need to format the input parameter in Apex form before calling Oracle Procedure or do I need to change its format within the procedure.
Please help.

Comment: Are you passing the date as a parameter of data type `date` or `varchar2`? Better use the first one, this way you are independent of any date formatting.

Comment: Hi ,My parameter from apex form to calling DB procedure is..#OWNER#.PROC_REF_ARTICLE_NBR_UPDINSERT(V_VALID_FROM_DT=>TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:P293_VALID_FROM_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD');

Comment: First of all there is nothing called Date format in Oracle DB. A date is a date. You probably feel they are different because the client you are using formats it that way. Is the 'V_VALID_FROM_DT' parameter in your procedure a char or a date? You are converting it to a char date in the YYYY-MM-DD format. If the parameter is a date then Oracle may not implicitly convert it back to a date thus giving an error.

Answer (score 1):

APEX treats all item values as strings e.g. '16-AUG-2017'.  If the procedure you are calling expects a DATE parameter then you need to convert the value before calling it.  This will go against the grain for many people, but in an APEX application I would happily use an **implicit** conversion:

```
myproc (p_date => to_date(:P1_DATE));
```

This will work regardless of the date format setting in APEX.  The alternative is to perform an explicit conversion using the prevailing APEX date format like this:

```
myproc (p_date => to_date(:P1_DATE, :APP_NLS_DATE_FORMAT));
```

But that just seems redundant to me.

Of course, your procedure call is going to fail if the value in P1_DATE is not a valid date in the prevailing APEX date format, so you should validate that prior to calling the procedure.  You can do that using an APEX validation for example. Another way is to have an APEX procedure layer that accepts all values as strings, validates and converts them using some common utilities, and then calls the main procedure.

Comment: Hi Tony, I have tried both options-'myproc (p_date => to_date(:P1_DATE)); and myproc (p_date => to_date(:P1_DATE));' and 'myproc (p_date => to_date(:P1_DATE, :APP_NLS_DATE_FORMAT));' but both are not working  procedure is still failing and session level values still '20-AUG-2017'

Comment: Is the procedure parameter of type DATE?  If it is this will work.  Sounds like your procedure expects a formatted string, in which case your only option is to reformat the date as it wants it like `to_char(to_date(:P1_DATE),'YYYY-MM-DD')`